# Issue setting up a save path with integer variables and strings in kdb+

Tags: string, append, kdb

I am basically trying to save to `data/${EPOCH_TIME}`:

```
begin_unix_time: "J"$first system "date +%s"
\t:1 save `data/"string"$"begin_unix_time"
```

I am expecting it to save to `data/1578377178`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to cast `first system "date +%s"` to a long in this case, since you want to attach one string to another. Instead you can use

```
begin_unix_time:first system "date +%s"
```

to store the string of numbers:

```
q)begin_unix_time
"1578377547"
q)`$"data/",begin_unix_time
`data/1578377547
```

Here you use the [comma](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/join/) `,` to join one string to another, then using [cast](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cast/) `` `$ `` to convert the string to a symbol.

The keyword [save](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/save/) is saving global data to a file. Given your filepath, it looks like youre trying to save down a global variable named `1578377547`, and kdb can not handle variable names being purely numbers.

You might want to try saving a variable named `a1578377547` instead, for example. This would change the above line to

```
q)`$"data/a",begin_unix_time
`data/a1578377547
```

and your save would work correctly, *given that the global variable `a1578377547` exists*. Because you are sourcing the date down to the second from linux directly in the line you are saving a variable down to, this will likely not work, due to time constantly changing!

Also note that the [timer](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syscmds/#t-timer) system command will repeat it the execution `n` times (as in `\t:n`), meaning that the same variable will save down mutliple times given the second does not change. The time will also likely change for large `n` and you wont have anything assigned to the global variable you are trying to save should the second change.

Comment: i appreciate it :)